How to prevent user from viewing app content in screenshot in ios in my flutter app
In my flutter app, I want that whenever a user is taking a screenshot, then on some specific pages, my app content should not be visible. To tackle this, I used some native kotlin code to implement this in android, but for ios, i am facing some issues.
I made method channels to implement this functionality and wrote some native swift code for the same.
Here is my AppDelegate File:
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_downloader
import GoogleMaps
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var blackOverlayView: UIView?
    var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        guard let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
            print("Error: RootViewController is not FlutterViewController")
            return false
        }

        methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my_channel_name",
                                           binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

        methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler { [weak self] (call, result) in
            guard let self = self else {
                result(FlutterError(code: "ERROR", message: "Self is nil", details: nil))
                return
            }

            switch call.method {
            case "preventScreenshots":
                print("Inside my prevent screenshot")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Inside 1")
                    guard let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
                        print("Inside else")
                        result(FlutterError(code: "ERROR", message: "Root view controller not found", details: nil))
                        return
                    }
                    print("Inside 2")
                    let field = UITextField()
                    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
                    print("Inside 3")
                    field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    controller.view.addSubview(field)
                    print("Inside 4")
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerYAnchor),
                        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerXAnchor)
                    ])
                    print("Inside 5")
                }
                result(nil)
            case "allowScreenshots":
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    controller.view.subviews.forEach { view in
                        if view is UITextField {
                            view.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                    }
                }
                result(nil)
            case "showBlackOverlay":
                self.showBlackOverlay()
                result(nil)
            case "hideBlackOverlay":
                self.hideBlackOverlay()
                result(nil)
            case "addScreenshotListener":
                self.addScreenshotObserver()
                result(nil)
            case "removeScreenshotListener":
                self.removeScreenshotObserver()
                result(nil)
            default:
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("my_api_key")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPlugins)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: { _, _ in }
            )
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    @objc private func handleScreenshotNotification() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let controller = self.window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else { return }
            print("Listened to screenshot, now calling method")
            self.methodChannel?.invokeMethod("preventScreenshots", arguments: nil)
        }
    }

    private func addScreenshotObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.handleScreenshotNotification),
            name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        print("Screenshot listener added")
    }

    private func removeScreenshotObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
            self,
            name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        print("Screenshot listener removed")
    }

    private func showBlackOverlay() {
        guard let window = self.window else { return }
        if blackOverlayView == nil {
            blackOverlayView = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
            blackOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            blackOverlayView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            window.addSubview(blackOverlayView!)
        }
        blackOverlayView?.isHidden = false
    }

    private func hideBlackOverlay() {
        blackOverlayView?.isHidden = true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: dataDict
        )
    }
}

private func registerPlugins(registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("FlutterDownloaderPlugin")) {
        FlutterDownloaderPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "FlutterDownloaderPlugin")!)
    }
}

Here is how i am calling my method channel:
class AppMethodChannels {
  static const _channel = MethodChannel("eduvate_admin/channel");

  ///Currently implemented for android only
  ///This method prevents user from taking screenshots
  static void preventScreenshots() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      _channel.invokeMethod('preventScreenshots');
    }
  }

  ///Currently implemented for android only
  ///This method allows user to take screenshots
  static void allowScreenshots() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
      _channel.invokeMethod('allowScreenshots');
    }
  }

  ///Shows a black overlay on the screen.
  ///Currently implemented for iOS only
  static void showBlackOverlay() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _channel.invokeMethod('showBlackOverlay');
    }
  }

  ///Hides the black overlay from the screen.
  ///Currently implemented for iOS only
  static void hideBlackOverlay() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _channel.invokeMethod('hideBlackOverlay');
    }
  }

  static void setScreenshotListener() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      print("Setting ss listener");
      _channel.invokeMethod("addScreenshotListener");
    }
  }
}

I am calling setScreenshotListener in initstate of my page.
Now, I don't know swift, but from what I can understand is, when I will call addScreenshotListener from my method channel,
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.handleScreenshotNotification),
            name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification,
            object: nil
        )

This part of code will run, and it is some kind of listener which will trigger the function, which is passed in selector whenever a notification comes.
Now, in the handleScreenshotNotification method, I have called
self.methodChannel?.invokeMethod("preventScreenshots", arguments: nil) which should trigger the preventScreenshots method which I declared above.
Now, this print statement is printing, print("Listened to screenshot, now calling method") but all of the print statements in my preventScreenshots method are not printing, i.e. my method is not being called.
So, I tried to write the same code inside my listener, instead of calling the function, all statements were printing, but I was not able to achieve the desired output.
Can someone help me out with this? Like, why my method is not being called and why the code for blank/empty screen is not working?

Note that the event is called userDidTakeScreenShot, not userWillTakeScreenshot any changes you make to your view in response to this event is too late. The screen shot has already been taken. There is no official way to prevent screenshots on iOS.

However, why are you trying to invoke your function via the method channel. When your code is responding to the notification you are already in the app delegate code. You can call your Swift function directly.

Yes yes, I realised that. I was just made these functions for other use, but in this case, there is absolutely no need. But like how whatsapp does it, or is there any other way through which i can do this?

I found a solution using this package https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector
which is working fine for ios and android, as it will show a blank view for screenshot. I think we can change it's code and display our custom widget/image.
